# MatLab: Classdef for polynomials error

Tags: matlab

I have written the following class for polynomials but i keep getting the error

```
No public field polynomial exists for class Poly.

Error in Poly (line 13)
                obj.polynomial=struct('exponent',{p.exponent},'coeff',{p.coeff});
```

Here is my class

```
classdef Poly

    properties
        polynomial

    end

    methods
        function obj=Poly(p)
            if isa(p,'Poly')
                obj=p;
            else
                obj.polynomial=struct('exponent',{p.exponent},'coeff',{p.coeff});
            end
        end
        function answer=plus(obj1,obj2)
            obj1=Poly(obj1);
            obj2=Poly(obj2);
            answer=Poly(addPoly(obj1.polynomial,obj2.polynomial));
        end
        function answer=mtimes(obj1,obj2)
            obj1=Poly(obj1);
            obj2=Poly(obj2);
            answer=Poly(multPoly(obj1.polynomial,obj2.polynomial));
        end
        function answer=rem(obj1,obj2)
            obj1=Poly(obj1);
            obj2=Poly(obj2);
            answer=Poly(dividePolyrem(obj1.polynomial,obj2.polynomial));
       end





    end


end
```

I am unsure why I keep getting this error,I have tried adding `(SetAccess=Public)` after `properties` but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code is fine (besides the missing `end` for classdef and methods), probably there is an exists an outdated version of the class, which prevents matlab to update the class definition. Clear all variables containing instances of `Poly`.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-and-reloading-classes.html